# A Combination of Graph Theory and Number Theory

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, contest-math

Let $d_n$ be the number of distinct simple connected graphs on the same set of $n$ vertices, where two simple connected graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$, on the same set of $n$ vertices, are said to be distinct if there exists at least one pair of vertices $(x,y)$ such that $x$ and $y$ is connected by an edge in $G_1$ but not in $G_2$.

Now suppose that $p$ is an $odd$ $prime$ and $n=p+1$

Hence prove that $d_n^2\equiv 1$ (mod $p$).

Comment: @Useless I was trying to use the Fermat's theorem but failed

Comment: @Useless But the calculation would be so messy

Comment: @Useless Actually in this problem we are not asked to find the nature or closed form of $d_n$ but that congruence which may be done indirectly without knowing the proper nature of $d_n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Arrange the vertices as a regular $p$-gon  with a point in the centre. Split the connected graphs into classes where two graphs are in the same class if one is obtained from the other by rotating the polygon.

Now every connected graph where the centre vertex has degree less than $p$ is in a class of size exactly $p$ (why?). How many other connected graphs are there?

Comment: Degree of the centre vertex is not all that important. The graphs are split in two large classes: those which are _symmetric_ under this cyclic permutation, and those which are not. The latter come in flocks of $p$ and hence are irrelevant. The former are a powerset of _non-equivalent_ edges, of which there are $p-1\over2$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I have a question that how to start thinking for such problems?

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattachrya Well, it goes as follows: we think about $d_n$ for a while and realize that searching for explicit formula is hopeless. Then again, since we are considering things $\pmod p$, it would be natural to single out some unknown part of $d_n$ which is divisible by $p$ and skip it altogether. To assemble graphs in groups of $p$, it is natural to use some symmetry of order $p$, which may be thought of as the rotational symmetry mentioned by **Especially Lime**.

Comment: @IvanNeretin but how can I realize that such rotational symmetry will work.I want a source of this kind of problems so that I can acquire knowledge about how to proceed in the right way while solving such problems

Comment: It will work because this symmetry operation generates a group of order $p$. With $p$ prime, it can't have subgroups. Hence any graph is either symmetric (which we may count later), or it will produce a class of $p$ equivalent graphs, which we don't bother counting, because $\pmod p$ and stuff. As for the source of more problems in discrete math, you'd better start a separate question.

Comment: @IvanNeretin can you suggest me good books with related problems for beginning?

Comment: No. I find my problems here on math.SE.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I have posted a new Combinatorial Geometry Problem plz check it

Comment: @IvanNeretin I gave my own solution and asked for alternative solutions